# [Flutter][web] When setting alignment property of IconButton, how to also move hover & splash animations positions?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

When I create a large button, in this case an ImageButton and move its child (`icon`) to the bottom right corner using `alignment: Alignment.bottomRight`, the icon does move, but the hover & splash animations remain in the center of the button.

Is there a way to move the animations with the icon so that the entire area is still clickable and the animations react to the entire area as well?

Example:
[image]

Access a working example [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=1e5920eb3a31a5687afbae83f3665396)